# Calling "super" keyword with modules and inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance, module, mixins, super

I thought that including a module as a mixin in a class "added the functions" to the class.

I do not understand why this does not work as expected:

```
module A
    def blah
        super if defined?(super)
        puts "hello, world!"
    end
end

class X
    include A
end

class Y < X
    include A
end

y = Y.new
y.blah
```

I was expecting "y" to call its super blah() (since its included in class X?) but instead i got:

> test.rb:3:in blah: super: no superclass method `blah'

Answer (score 12):

You're running into nuances of Ruby's object hierarchy and how method lookups interact with included modules.

When you invoke a method on a object, [Ruby walks over the `ancestors` list](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Lookup) for the object's class, looking for an ancestor class or module that responds to that method. When you invoke `super` in that method, you're effectively *continuing* your walking up the tree of `ancestors`, looking for the *next* object that responds to the same method name.

The ancestor tree for your `X` and `Y` classes look like this:

```
p X.ancestors #=> [ X, A, Object, Kernel, BaseObject ]
p Y.ancestors #=> [ Y, X, A, Object, Kernel, BaseObject ]
```

The problem is that `include`ing the module a second time, in a child class, does *not* inject a second copy of the module in the ancestors chain.

Effectively what is happening is when you invoke `Y.new.blah`, Ruby begins looking for a class that responds to `blah`. It walks past `Y`, and `X`, and lands on `A` which introduces the `blah` method.  When `A#blah` invokes `super`, the "pointer" into your ancestor list is already pointing at `A`, and Ruby resumes looking from that point for another object responding to `blah`, starting with `Object`, `Kernel`, and then `BaseObject`. None of these classes have a `blah` method, so your `super` invocation fails.

A similar thing happens if a module `A` includes a module `B`, and then a class includes both module `A` and `B`. The `B` module is *not* included twice:

```
module A; end
module B; include A; end

class C
  include A
  include B
end

p C.ancestors # [ C, B, A, Object, Kernel, BaseObject ]
```

Note that it's `C, B, A`, not `C, A, B, A`.

The intent would seem to be to allow you to safely invoke `super` inside any of `A`'s methods without worrying about how consuming class hierarchies may inadvertently include `A` twice.

---

There are a few experiments that demonstrate different aspects of this behavior. The first is adding a `blah` method to Object, which allows the `super` call to pass:

```
class Object; def blah; puts "Object::blah"; end; end

module A
  def blah
    puts "A::blah"
    super
  end
end

class X
    include A
end

class Y < X
    include A
end

Y.new.blah

# Output
# A::blah
# Object::blah
```

The second experiment is to use two modules, `BaseA` and `A`, which *does* cause the modules to be inserted twice, correctly, in the `ancestors` chain:

```
module BaseA
  def blah
    puts "BaseA::blah"
  end
end

module A
  def blah
    puts "A::blah"
    super
  end
end

class X
  include BaseA
end

class Y < X
  include A
end

p Y.ancestors # [ Y, A, X, BaseA, Object, ...]
Y.new.blah

# Output
# A::blah
# BaseA::blah
```

A third experiement uses `prepend`, instead of `include`, which places the module *in front* of the object in the `ancestors` hierarchy and interestingly  **does** insert a duplicate copy of the module. This allows us to reach the point where effectively `Y::blah` invokes `X::blah`, which fails because `Object::blah` does not exist:

```
require 'pry'

module A
  def blah
    puts "A::blah"
    begin
      super
    rescue
      puts "no super"
    end
  end
end

class X
  prepend A
end

class Y < X
  prepend A
end

p Y.ancestors # [ A, Y, A, X, Object, ... ]
Y.new.blah

# Output
# A::blah (from the A before Y)
# A::blah (from the A before X)
# no super (from the rescue clause in A::blah)
```

Comment: Very interesting and instructive. What do you mean by "I cannot fully explain" at the beginning of your opening sentence.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I meant that this answer relies on hypothesis and experimentation that seem to support that hypothesis, rather than an authoritative explanation and a link to supporting documentation.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Anyways I updated the wording slightly.

Comment: This may be part of the reference you were looking for with regards to method lookup: http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Lookup